# IF this class exists, OR this class doesn't exist, do something with jQuery and submit form - but won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, if-statement

I have a form, and when a user selects a clothing size, the form is submitted, but if they don't select any size, an error message appears. This part works perfectly, however there are times when no size options exists (for example, when buying a wallet). 
When there is a size option, an li element with a class of "size-attribute" is there, and within this li is another ul -> li with the class es-value, and when the user selects an es-value, it is given a class of selected. It looks something like this:

```
<li class="size-attribute>
 <ul>
  <li class="es-value"></li>
  <li class="es-value selected"></li>
  <li class="es-value"></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

However, when there is No size to select (like for a wallet), the list item with the class size-attribute doesn't exist. I am trying to write my code so that when an es-value with a class of selected exists, or NO size-attribute exists at all, the form will submit. However, with the code I have written, when I click add to bag, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form');
            if( $( ".es-value.selected" ).length || !$("li .size-attribute")) {
                $form.submit();
            } else {
                $("#errormessage").show();
                $("#error-border").addClass("error-border");
            }
```

Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong, and why the form won't submit?

Comment: What proceeds the `.on('click'` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the .hasClass() method from jQuery to check if any size-attributes exist.

```
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form');
    if( $( ".es-value.selected" ).length || !$("li").hasClass("size-attribute")){
        $form.submit();
    } else {
        $("#errormessage").show();
        $("#error-border").addClass("error-border");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with in the condition: `( $( ".es-value.selected" ).length || !$("li .size-attribute"))`

The second part, `!$("li .size-attribute"))` will always return false. The reason for this, is that `$(...)` returns an object. An object, in javascript, is always truthy, so `!$(...)` is always false-y.

Finally, `$("li .size-attribute")` does not actually represent the thing you are looking for. `li .size-attribute` represents an element with class `size-attribute` inside of an element of type `li`, what you want is `$("li.size-attribute")` - an element of type `li`, with a class of `size-attribute`

If you structure it the same way as the first part and fix the css query, it will work, eg. `( $( ".es-value.selected" ).length || !$("li.size-attribute").length)`

Although I would generally lean towards a more descriptive approach:

```
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form');

            if( $( ".es-value.selected" ).length > 0) {
                // a size was selected
                $form.submit();
            } else if ($("li.size-attribute").length === 0) {
                // No size option was present
                $form.submit();
            } else {
                $("#errormessage").show();
                $("#error-border").addClass("error-border");
            }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these options worked - in both cases, the form will submit even when there is a li size-attribute and i haven't selected a size, instead of giving the error message.

Comment: hmmmm, if it wasn't submitting at all before, and now it is always submitting, I would say that there is something else going on I may not be able to tell without the rest of the code/html. Although I did just notice that the part of the condition I copied also has another small typo in it - updating the answer now for that

Comment: Oh actually that typo explains the problem, I expect this may work now for you